# The definition of polynomials in multiple indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I came across the notation $\mathbb{Q}[t_1, t_2, ..., t_n]$ in Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory*, which is never explicitly defined. I wonder: does $\mathbb{Q}[t_1, t_2, ..., t_n]$ consist of only polynomials of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+py^3+qy^2+ry+s$, or does it also contain a polynomial such as $ax^3+bx^3y^2+cx^2y+py^2+qxy+rx$? Please help if you can-many thanks in advance!

Comment: The last, yes. Polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$, otherwise the product of two polynomials may not also be there. For example $\frac{2}{3}t_1t_2+t^4_3$ is in $\Bbb Q[t_1,\ldots, t_n]$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout thank you so much!

Comment: Recursively: $R[x,y]\cong R[x][y]$ = poly's in $\,y\,$ with coef's in $R[x]$, e.g. your latter is $(bx^3+p)\, y^2 + (cx^2+qx)\,y + (ax^3+rx)\, y^0.\,$ And $R[x,y,z] \cong R[x,y][z] = $ polys in $\,z\,$ with coef's  in $\,R[x][y]\,$ of above form, etc, etc.